# Building version control system for website, like the one used on Wikipedia but for geospatial data?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, openlayers, web-mapping, github

I'm working on a website permitting to display and modify geospatial data. So far, I'm using this solution:

- My data is stored in PostgreSQL with the extension PostGIS
- It is posted in GeoServer
- My website uses OpenLayers to request the tiles I need from GeoServer with WMS and WFS

Now I would like to keep the memory of the previous versions of the geospatial data. On Wikipedia, users can read an article, modify it or check the discussion page of the article to see the previous commits. I would like to have the same possibilities with the geospatial data:

- A page to see an element (let's say a multipolygon)
- A page to modify it and a page to see all the commits made with this element (with the author, the date and the size of each commit
- And the possibility to click on a commit to see the geospatial data of the element at the time of the commit)

I tried to see what existed on the internet and it sounds like what I need is a version control system (like the one on Github) for geospatial data. Geogig (http://geogig.org/) seems to be the one. But I'm not quite sure I understand all this well. According to my needs, do you think a version control system and more especially Geogig could be a solution?

Also, even if Geogig can do the job, I'm not sure How I could make it work. As I understand it, I would put an extension to use Geogig in GeoServer and Geogig would be an intermediate between PostgreSQL and GeoServer. Does it mean I would keep the connection PostgreSQL<->GeoServer for the current data (so for the display page and the modification page of an element) and the connection PostgreSQL<->Geogig<->GeoServer for the past commits (so for the discussion page of an element)?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://sno.earth/? "Sno stores geospatial and tabular data in Git, providing version control at the row and cell level."

Comment: From what I see on their website, sno.earth sounds like something you use locally, not like something you use to run a website. I think what I'm looking for is really what Wikipedia is using to keep a track of all the previous versions of an article, but suited to spatial data instead of text